# Why does this Task go directly from WaitingForActivation to RanToCompletion?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm running the following code in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    Task x = TestAsync();

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Status);
    } while (x.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
}

public async static Task TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return;
}
```

The output is:

```
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
WaitingForActivation
RanToCompletion
```

Why does it go directly from `WaitingForActivation` to `RanToCompletion`? Why is it apparently never in the `Running` state?

Comment: Note: I am deliberately not `await`ing the Task in this case.

Comment: @Hydragyrum: Check out the [state machine diagrams](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html) on my blog.